# What if I deleted the Info.plist file

Tags: xcode

I accordantly deleted the Info.plist file and the things inside.  How do I get a new Info.plist file?

I tried creating a new XCode project and transferring the Info.plist file from it to the project I'm working on and add it as my Info.plist file.  I tried looking in the trash can but things in the file are not there.

Comment: You don't work with version control?!

Comment: No. I should have.